# amd64 Packages 404 Not Found while sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, sudo, 64-bit

Can anyone comment on the following error while `sudo apt-get update`?

```
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fenics-packages/fenics-1.5.x/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages  404  Not Found
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: That PPA doesn't have anything for Xenial -  16.04.